# Is there any way to find which direction Rails toggle method worked?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

ActiveRecord has the [toggle method](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-toggle) which assigns to attribute the boolean opposite of attribute?. I was using this. Now, I want to know which direction that method worked i.e. it set the attribute? to true or false. But since I used that method with symbolized parameter, I cannot call attribute? directly like below.

```
role = params[:role]
role = role.to_sym
@user.roles.toggle(role)
```

I know I can use instance.send method, but I consider it as anti-pattern because it depends on the name of the method. Is there any way to know the direction the toggle worked?

Comment: `toggle` is using `public_send` under the hood and the only way to know which direction it worked, is to check value after check. You could overwrite `toggle` method on model with something like:
```
  def toggle(attribute)
      super(attribute)
      self[attribute]
    end
```
You could also name it in different way so you wouldn't break public interface of original `toggle` method. I don't think there is a bettery way to achieve what you need.

Comment: @BartoszBonisławski "the only way to know which direction it worked, is to check value after check." That's not correct at all, there's method `changes` that gives you exactly this answer.

Comment: Which is not so much different from using `send` method since it depends on name of atribute. I wouldn't call it a clean solution

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I just realized that you're calling `toggle` on a relation. The answer below is for toggle on a model. As I can't check it live on the relation ATM, I'll leave this answer until I can update it for relations. Maybe it will point you into the right direction with the linked docs.

There's a whole rails module https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html that handles just that. You can use `changes` method (https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html#method-i-changes) which will give you an answer of what was before and what is now:

```rb
role = params[:role]
role = role.to_sym
@user.toggle(role)

@user.changes[role] # => [false, true]
```

`[false, true]` means that it was `false` and became `true`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Stefan, I can figure out. The answer was super easy (at least) in my case.

```
role = params[:role]
role = role.to_sym
@user.toggle(role)
if @user.roles.include?(role)
  // toggled to set it
else
  // toggled to unset it
end
```

Really, really, thank you for all answers.